# Jenkins | ssh not working

Tags: linux, bash

I am doing ssh to servers which has password less authentication from jenkins server to these servers in /tmp/san.txt by running a shell script.

```
jenkins@pc4mobjen01:/tmp> cat check.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /tmp/sand.txt`
do
ssh -q mpdevops@"$i"
bash /app/home/mpdevops/sand.sh
done


jenkins@pc4mobjen01:/tmp> bash check.sh
Last login: Wed Apr 19 09:20:03 2017 from 10.4.70.42
 Powered by Monsoon (Version 2.2.1519)         Platform: suse 11.3
 Hostname     : mo-97df9aafa.dc19.saas.sap.cor Name    : PC19MOBDEVOPS01
 Organization : saas_prod                      Project : dc19_production
 Url          : https://monsoon.mo.sap.corp/instances/mo-97df9aafa
mo-97df9aafa[PC19MOBDEVOPS01]:~ # logout
bash: /app/home/mpdevops/sand.sh: No such file or directory
```

But sand.sh is present.

```
mo-97df9aafa[PC19MOBDEVOPS01]:~ # cat sand.sh
for j in `cat sand.txt`
do
ssh -q mpdevops@"$j"
sudo python /tmp/test.py
done
```

Please help.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the command to be executed on the remote client on the same line as the actual ssh command. Looks like the bash command is being executed on the local host as opposed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `sand.sh` on the same line with `ssh` command:

**check.sh** should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /tmp/sand.txt`
do
ssh -q mpdevops@"$i" "bash /app/home/mpdevops/sand.sh"
done
```